# image not displaying inside an activity after capturing the image from camera in android

Tags: android

I have written a program which has a button which when clicked captures a photo through camera and want to set the captured image on the same activity below the button.

Everything works without giving an error. The image is also getting saved to the respective location. But the image is not getting displayed, which means something is going wrong.

[image: screenshot of my application in which below the button I want the captured image to be displayed]

Below is my Code for the above :

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b1;
    private File imageFile;
    ImageView img;
    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPicture);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                imageFile = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                        "test.jpeg");
                uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (requestCode == 0 && data != null) {
            switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(
                            MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                    previewCapturedImage();

                    img.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File was not saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(),
                    options);

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you press `Ok` button after capturing image, you can take the captured image from the `Extras` using `Intent`(data in your case) parameter received through `onActivityResult`
Simply use this code inside `onActivityResult`

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    imgViewLogo.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Comment: i even tried this sir , but image not getting displayed

Comment: have you put this code outside the `(imageFile.exists())` check ?

Comment: if (imageFile.exists()) {
     Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
     img.setImageBitmap(photo); 
}
 else {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File was not saved",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

Comment: I want to know which body of code is executing ? if or else ?

Comment: sir i added another else part after my switch closes in which i added "File not displayed" so its executing this else , my if is not getting executed

Comment: remove that if else check and add the code directly after checking case `Activity.RESULT_OK:`

Comment: its giving a Runtime Exception , logcat says Failure Delivering result ResultInfo who=null , request=0 , result=-1 , data = null

Comment: try to change extends `ActionBarActivity` to simple `Activity`

Comment: sir i got it at last , i removed the if condition to check my resultcode and requestcode and simply checked whether my file exists or not and set my imageview to bitmap , i would like to say thanx for ur participation in guiding me

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (requestCode == 0 && data != null) {
            switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                     private String selectedImagePath;
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String filePath = null;
            String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                            filePath = selectedImagePath;
                        } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                            filePath = filemanagerstring;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.unknownPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             if (filePath != null) {
                            decodeFile(filePath);
                        } else {
                            bitmap = null;
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File was not saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //getPath method

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    //decodeFile method

    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
            try {

                File f = new File(filePath);
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                int angle = 0;

                if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    angle = 90;
                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    angle = 180;
                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    angle = 270;
                }

                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                mat.postRotate(angle);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
                ByteArrayOutputStream outstudentstreamOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outstudentstreamOutputStream);
                img.setImageBitmap(selfieBitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: sir replaced your code with mine but still its not displaying my image

Comment: @arjunnarahari any error are you getting? and on which device are you testing?

Comment: no error sir , my own device htc one x , sir do i need to add anything inside manifest.xml , like <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Comment: @arjunnarahari debug your code, in onActivityResult method and see what happened

Comment: i did sir , it shows requestcode = 0 , resultcode = -1 , data = null

Comment: @arjunnarahari ya then you not getting anything in callback, that means camera not returning image. Now check in your code.

Comment: @arjunnarahari try , uri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: sir may i ask what should i put in place of values ?? , what does values mean here ?

Comment: use this :Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
- See more at: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample/#sthash.p59RsYHP.dpuf

Comment: sir i got it at last , i removed the if condition to check my resultcode and requestcode and simply checked whether my file exists or not and set my imageview to bitmap , i would like to say thanx for ur participation in guiding me